# how to populate a drop down list from my SQL database using php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to populate a drop down list from my sql database using php, but it shows the below error:

> "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   object given in C:\wamp\www\Q&A\signup.php on line 43"

my code is:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT category_name FROM category ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Query to get data from category failed: ".mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $category_name=$row["category_name"];
    echo "<option>" . $category_name . "</option>";
                }
 ?>
```

Comment: Mixing mysqli with mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using old function `mysql_fetch_array` it should be `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Also `mysql_error` should be `mysqli_error` which accepts connection as single parameter.

Update your code like this,

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT category_name FROM category ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Query to get data from category failed: ".mysqli_error(conn));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $category_name=$row["category_name"];
    echo "<option>" . $category_name . "</option>";
                }
 ?>
```

I'm assuming you've a valid connection to the database in `$conn` variable.